# Got 'unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' message, after assigning value to NSLayoutConstraints.constant

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have to change a constraint value(which is `height` value) during execution, from 19 to 45.

To do this, I added the constraint property.

`@IBOutlet weak var cnst: NSLayoutConstraint!`

And then I wrote the following one.

`cnst.constant = 45`

Then I got this message:

```
2016-08-04 11:19:49.352 IMOZOMO[45034:538195] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff278c27e70 V:[UIView:0x7ff278c27f40(45)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff27a9b1ee0 V:[UIView:0x7ff278c27f40(19)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff278c27e70 V:[UIView:0x7ff278c27f40(45)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Seems like the previous property still remains and the height of the designated object did not change. I thought the constraint with height of 19 might disappear.

How can I change the constant value of NSLayoutConstraint?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you don't have two constraints specifying a height of `19` to begin with? Because the way you're adjusting the constant is OK, it must be some other problem.

Comment: @paulvs There are some other constraints for the object but only one of them limits its height.

Comment: It look like your other constraint is conflicting with the new height. Look at your constraint that is affecting the `.y` and see what is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As error says, You have got a conflict in your constraints on height Constraint value = 45.**

Now, at height 19, it might be satisfying the hierarchy, but on 45, it is conflicting.

**SOLUTION:**

**Try setting the height constraint to 45 in your interface builder, and it should show you the error right away.**